# proftpd configuration issue

Tags: ftp, sftp, proftpd

I have installed `proftpd` file server using `apt-get`

But after adding User as shown below:

```
sudo useradd myproftpduser 

sudo passwd myproftpduser

sudo usermod -m -d /var/www/ myproftpduser
```

and after restarting `proftpd` service I am not able to login with the new user.

I am able to login only with `proftpd` user.

Not sure where I am making mistake

Answer (score -1):

The right way to create user in proftpd

sudo useradd myproftpduser -d /var/www/myproftpduser -s /bin/false